# Converting to time format - Shows error - Unknown timezone

Tags: r, posixct

[image]

I have dataset in this format 1/2/2015 9:43

I am not sure why the code below showing me warnings.

```
in_time <- sapply(in_time, function(x) as.POSIXlt(x, origin="1-2-2015","%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
```

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

The errors are:

> In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'

Comment: What warnings did you get? Have you tried `warnings()`? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Well to start, you specify `format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"` yet you say your dataset has format `1/2/2015 9:43`. This works just fine `as.POSIXlt("1/2/2015 9:43", origin = "1-2-2015", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

Comment: @Mauritis in_time <- sapply(in_time, function(x) as.POSIXlt(x, origin="1-2-2015","%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: Please edit your question, when you provide new information.

Comment: @wynethomas You should include some minimal sample data (i.e. some date entries that are representative of your data); as I say in my comment above, if I fix the `format` I don't get any warnings, so your problem is either a simple typo and/or not reproducible.

Comment: @wynethomas You need to take a look at the link kath provides in her first comment. Please make your example reproducible! Include sample data!

Comment: @MauritsEvers Included sample dataset as image in the question

Comment: Please provide your data in a reproducible format. See the link in my first comment. Use for example `dput()`

Comment: `lapply` gives better results than `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that `as.POSIXlt` isn't able to determine your system's time zone, e.g. if `Sys.timezone()` is returning `NA`.

You can specify a timezone manually using the `tz` argument, e.g.:

```
in_time <- sapply(in_time, function(x) {
    as.POSIXlt(x, origin="1-2-2015","%d-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz = "Europe/London")
})
```

A list of valid time zones you can supply to `tz` can be found using the `OlsonNames()` function (see also `help("time zones")`).